# Display Google's search result in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, google-search

I would like to know if there is a way to display Google's search results as an output in my Python program. Like if I type "Electricity" in my program then I want to display Google's search results as plain text. Is there a way to do it?

**UPDATE**

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning")
the_page = response.read(bytes)
content = str(the_page)
print the_page
```

I tried the above code but it is showing me errors, if I just type

```
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

It just prints the HTML format of the page but not the text string so How do I get the string alone?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: Please ask questions about your code, not about coding in general. Anyway I have posted an answer.

Comment: @CPanda Look at my update, pls help me....

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning")
content= response.read()
# Now it's time for parsing *content* to extract the relevant data
# Use regex, HTMLParser from standard library
# or use beautifulsoup, LXML (third party)
```